# Android multi touch view resize flickering

Tags: android

I have a view with a custom implementation - I can draw on it, and I am adding this view on runtime into an `RelativeLayout` layout like so:

```
  RelativeLayout paintRootView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_view);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
  paintView.setLayoutParams(params);

  PaintView paintView = new PaintView(context);
  paintRootView.addView(paintView);
```

I have some controls that specify when `onTouch` method draw on the view / drag the view or resize the view. Drawing and translate view works fine but when I try to zoom in or out, this view is flikering. Do I miss sometring?

[video effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNqTYIl3hXU&feature=youtu.be)

Used code:

```
private int mode = NONE;
private float oldDist;
private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 0.5f;
private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 3.0f;


 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (IS_IN_MOOVING_STATE) {
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                // some code for drag
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                oldDist = getSpacing(event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                  // some code for drag

                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = getSpacing(event);

                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;

                    PointF pointF = getMidPoint(event);

                    if (scale >= MIN_ZOOM && scale < MAX_ZOOM) {
                        zoomPaintView(scale, scale, pointF);
                    }
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        paintRootView.invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: could you fix your problem?

Comment: @ Mahdi.Pishguy nope

Comment: could you try this link? https://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/

Comment: i'm trying to use this tutorial for resize `RecyclerView` items

Answer (score 0):

i hope to help you. this is pseudo code, and by that i can change TextView size by MultiTouch event

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    final static float STEP = 200;
    TextView mytv;
    float mRatio = 1.0f;
    int   mBaseDist;
    float mBaseRatio;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mytv.setTextSize(mRatio + 13);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
            int action     = event.getAction();
            int pureaction = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            if (pureaction == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
                mBaseDist = getDistance(event);
                mBaseRatio = mRatio;
            } else {
                float delta = (getDistance(event) - mBaseDist) / STEP;
                float multi = (float) Math.pow(2, delta);
                mRatio = Math.min(1024.0f, Math.max(0.1f, mBaseRatio * multi));
                mytv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (mRatio + 13), (int) (mRatio + 13)));
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    int getDistance(MotionEvent event) {
        int dx = (int) (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        int dy = (int) (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        return (int) (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```